# magento upgrade 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.8 using admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

**I am working currently magento 1.9.0.1.**
how to update magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow this steps.

1. Open Magento Admin
2. System -> Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager
3. Make the login using your admin credentials.
4. Click on button "Check for Upgrades" like image : https://prnt.sc/j561ar
5. Select Version Only for "Mage_All_Latest" from dropdown like image : https://prnt.sc/j561vj
6. Click on button "Commit Changes"
7. Logout from admin
8. Remove cache and session folder from magento root -> var directory
9. Now Login again into admin and check.

Comment: It is never a good idea to remove session folder as all your customers' data in sessions will be deleted. It is not the best user experience and leads to the conversion rates drop.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to copy all folder and file from 1.9.3.8 and paste it to your root directory

Answer (score 0):

If anyone hasn't started the answer suggestion with backing up the database, and code base, then I'd consider the solution incorrect.

You're best bet is to ensure that you have a complete snapshot of code and database, then you may begin attempting upgrade solutions.

If I had to put in my two pennies, I'd first be certain that you are using some sort of method for checking the core hasn't been modified at all.  Check date timestamps to see if any files in the `app/code/core/*` are different or newer than the majority of the rest.

If you find that a lot of files in the core have been customized, then don't consider any upgrade until you know what will be overwritten.

If you are okay with overwriting some core code changes (which is the improper way to customize magento code) without double-checking the code, then you are taking a risk at breaking the site's functionality.

---

**Suggested Solution:**

Back-up database and codebase.  Duplicate the scenario on a development server.  Use version control system such as `git`, check-in the original code.  Create a new branch, back-up database, and then upgrade however you choose. Test thoroughly.  If you notice any issues, you can revert the codebase, source the previously dumped database, then investigate what the issue may be and test resolutions.

If you find a series of working steps and are feeling risky, back-up production database and code, then re-play those working steps on the production site.

Comment: thanks for answer but i can not understand your answer.